How to remap exceptions with Grape?
In a Ruby project using Grape, I have a custom exception Api::Exceptions::InvalidValueError that subclasses Grape::Exceptions::Base. If a validation fails (which causes Grape::Exceptions::ValidationErrors to be raised), I’d like to return the same response as if Api::Exceptions::InvalidValueError was raised.
Previously, I achieved it like this:
rescue_from Grape::Exceptions::ValidationErrors do |e|
    begin
        raise Api::Exceptions::InvalidValueError, e.full_messages
    rescue Api::Exceptions::InvalidValueError => invalid_value_error
        run_rescue_handler(:error_response, invalid_value_error)
    end
end

After upgrading to Grape 2.1.3, the above code fails with “undefined method run_rescue_handler”. With old versions of Grape, it worked because the block passed to rescue_from was executed in the context of the Grape::Middleware::Error instance that has #run_rescue_handler. However, with current versions of Grape, the block is executed in the context of the API endpoint instance, so Grape::Middleware::Error#run_rescue_handler can’t be called like this.
Is there a better way to achieve the goal that works with current versions of Grape?

What issue are you receiving currently? Is an error raised?  Unless I completely misunderstand the question it seems that using the builtin error! from the public API should work just fine. e.g. error!(invalid_value_error). Is there a reason this does not work for you?

I’ve added the specific error to the question.

Your proposed solution doesn’t work as is (sorry for not providing a full executable example!). error! from the public API throws something which is catched here and passed to that.

The handler called by the code snippet provided in the question does much more. I could copy what the latter does, but I’d prefer a more high-level way.

Can you add the full error including the stack trace? This will allow us to see the call stack and possibly provide better alternatives. Otherwise I would still use error! leveraging the same arguments provided by run_rescue_handler. Either that or just provide the desired output and we can possibly provide a custom handler to solve this.

What about adding a middleware to the stack that inherits from that Grape middleware? This way you're catching and reformatting all errors?
